# WinCvs 3 way diff with the "-3" option?

Tags: diff, command-line-arguments, wincvs

I'm working on writing a Perl script that provides an interface to WinCvs for all of my Perl scripts to use.  While trying to implement the `diff` command I came across an option that looks incredibly useful (if it does what I think it does) but I can't figure out how to use it.

Here is the "usage:" output for the WinCvs `diff` command.

[image]

> My question is what is ***how do you use the `-3` option?***

The online CVS documentation doesn't even reference this option and I can't figure out a way to make it produce a useful output.

I tried using it like this `cvs diff -3 -r<revision1> -r<revision2> -r<revision3>` but I just get the following error.

[image]

Using this command with only 2 revisions seems to give the same output as if I didn't use `-3`.  Am I missing something? Or is this command just inherently broken in WinCvs?

Comment: Are you sure "produce 3-way conflicts" means "perform a 3-way merge"?

Comment: No, I honestly have no clue what `-3` really does, but I can't find the answer anywhere.  If it does perform a 3-way merge that would be very useful to me, but if it does not, I would like to know what it really does and how to use it.